# How to break big columns into smaller columns

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-grid

I have a div that contains multiple tables of varying size (table data comes from backend).

The problem I'm trying to solve is break the bigger table(Feature 1 in the image) into smaller ones so they all fit in a single row of fixed size.

Another option was to make the other tables (Feature 2-5) stack below each other (prefer the first). [image]

```css
const container = css({ // main container
  boxSizing: 'border-box',
  margin: '40px auto',
  width: '90%'
});

const partName = css({  // header containing text 'Part A'
  fontSize: '1.2rem',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  padding: '0.5rem'
});

const tablesContainer = css({ // Div containing all feature tables
  display: 'grid',
  gridGap: '0.25rem',
  gridTemplateRows: 'minmax(15rem, auto)',
  gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(auto-fill, minmax(13rem, max-content))',
  gridAutoFlow: 'row',
  alignItems: 'baseline'
});

const featureTable = css({ // single feature table
  display: 'grid'
});

const featureName = css({ // feature header with bg color
  color: '#fff'
});

const featureRows = css({ // feature table cells
  '& th, td': {
    padding: '0.5rem',
  }
});
```

I've tried `gridTemplateRows: 'minmax(15rem, 30rem)'` but the table overlaps over another table in the 2nd row.

**Any suggestions are heartly welcome. Thank you :)**

Answer (score 1):

After long thinking I finally found the reason for the table not breaking off into multiple rows.

It is because the rows themselves are part of a single table body and the *< tbody >* can't break by itself using plain css (unless I force it using javascript).

So, in order to make the table rows slide over to new columns, I have to make a complete change - and that is by replacing the whole *< table >* element with multiples *< div >* structure.

That way I every rows are independent elements and obey the css rules more effectively.